# Выводиться ошибка при обращении к mysql

Tags: mysql

Выводиться вот такая ошибка при обращении к mysql

```
Access denied for user 'heimdaller'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

не существует такого пользователя для доступа в БД. Создай пользователя через phpMyAdmin

Comment: Но он есть. И я по этим данным в ручную авторизуюсь

Comment: @Слава Гесто, а привилегии выставлены?

Comment: Всё спасибо, проблема решена. Со стороны предоставляющей хостинг был удалён аккаунт после моего входа.

Comment: @Слава Гесто, это как? =)

Comment: Самому интересно